# How to decide where to store a method for accessing a database, if it interacts with two or more tables?

Tags: python, oop, flask, database-design, repository-pattern

I am a beginner on a coding bootcamp and I'm learning to make a CRUD app from scratch using Flask, Python, PostgresQL and psycopg. I'm trying to create the backend for a Twitter clone that has Users, Posts, Comments, Follows, Likes and Hashtags. To do this, I am making a model class and repository class for each of those elements. I've attached my ER diagram and seed SQL queries below.

I'm wondering as a general question, how do you decide where to store methods that interact with between two or more elements? For example, I want the following methods where `posts` interacts with `likes` and `comments`, where `posts` has a one-to-many relationship with each `likes` and `comments`, and I have the following guesses:

`.sort_posts_by_likes()` -- post_repository
`.get_all_likes_for_post(post_id)` -- like_repository
`.get_all_comments_for_post(post_id)` -- comment_repository

My general idea is to store the method in the 'many' side of the relationship, because I feel like the repository classes manage the *group* of the element in question

[image]

Database Seed below

```
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS users_id_seq;
CREATE TABLE users (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    email VARCHAR(255),
    password VARCHAR(255),
    handle VARCHAR(255),
    name VARCHAR(255),
    joined_on TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS posts_id_seq;
CREATE TABLE posts (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id INTEGER,
    content VARCHAR(255),
    created_on TIMESTAMP
    -- CONSTRAINT fk_users FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS comments_id_seq;
CREATE TABLE comments (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id INTEGER,
    post_id INTEGER,
    content VARCHAR(255),
    created_on TIMESTAMP
    -- CONSTRAINT fk_users FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    -- CONSTRAINT fk_posts FOREIGN KEY (post_id) REFERENCES posts(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS hashtags_id_seq;
CREATE TABLE hashtags (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(255)
);

-- Join tables
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS follows_id_seq;
CREATE TABLE follows (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    follower_id INTEGER,
    followee_id INTEGER
    -- CONSTRAINT fk_users FOREIGN KEY (follower_id) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    -- CONSTRAINT fk_users FOREIGN KEY (followee_id) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS likes_id_seq;
CREATE TABLE likes (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id INTEGER,
    post_id INTEGER NULL, -- can be blank
    comment_id INTEGER NULL -- can be blank
    -- CONSTRAINT fk_users FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    -- CONSTRAINT fk_posts FOREIGN KEY (post_id) REFERENCES posts(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    -- CONSTRAINT fk_comments FOREIGN KEY (comment_id) REFERENCES comments(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS hashtags_posts_id_sequence;
CREATE TABLE hashtags_posts (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    hashtag_id INTEGER,
    post_id INTEGER
    -- CONSTRAINT fk_hashtag FOREIGN KEY (hashtag_id) REFERENCES hashtags(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    -- CONSTRAINT fk_posts FOREIGN KEY (post_id) REFERENCES posts(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);


-- Then we inject some test data: ------------

-- CREATING USERS:
-- Creating 3 test users
INSERT INTO users (email, password, handle, name, joined_on) VALUES ('fifa_email@gmail.com', 'davidBeckam00@', 'FIFAcom', 'FIFA', '2015-07-28');
INSERT INTO users (email, password, handle, name, joined_on) VALUES ('bernie_email@gmail.com', 'feeltheBern12#', 'BernieSanders', 'Bernie Sanders', '2013-09-22');
INSERT INTO users (email, password, handle, name, joined_on) VALUES ('aoc_email@gmail.com', '1234567890a0C', 'AOC', 'Alexandria Ocasio-Cortez', '2017-06-01');



-- CREATE HASHTAGS:
-- Creating 3 hashtags
INSERT INTO hashtags (title) VALUES ('football');
INSERT INTO hashtags (title) VALUES ('memes');
INSERT INTO hashtags (title) VALUES ('shows');


-- MAKING POSTS:
-- User 1 makes Post 1 with Hashtag 1 and 3
INSERT INTO posts (user_id, content, created_on) VALUES (1, 'Has anyone seen the new David Beckham series?', '2023-10-16 12:30:00');
INSERT INTO hashtags_posts (hashtag_id, post_id) VALUES (3, 1);
INSERT INTO hashtags_posts (hashtag_id, post_id) VALUES (1, 1);

-- User 1 makes Post 2 with Hashtag 1, 2
INSERT INTO posts (user_id, content, created_on) VALUES (1, '"football" not "soccer", tyvm', '2023-10-17 10:30:00');
INSERT INTO hashtags_posts (hashtag_id, post_id) VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO hashtags_posts (hashtag_id, post_id) VALUES (2, 2);

-- User 2 makes Post 3 with Hashtags 1
INSERT INTO posts (user_id, content, created_on) VALUES (2, 'I am once again asking for your financial support', '2023-10-17 11:09:00');
INSERT INTO hashtags_posts (hashtag_id, post_id) VALUES (2, 3);


-- COMMENTING POSTS:
-- User 2 makes Comment 1 - Post 1
INSERT INTO comments (user_id, post_id, content, created_on) VALUES (2, 1, 'Yes it was sooo good!', '2023-10-16 19:05:00');
-- User 3 makes Comment 2 - Post 1
INSERT INTO comments (user_id, post_id, content, created_on) VALUES (3, 1, 'the scene where david asked posh about her dads car lollll', '2023-10-16 23:15:00');
-- User 3 makes Comment 3 - Post 2
INSERT INTO comments (user_id, post_id, content, created_on) VALUES (3, 2, 'classic', '2023-10-17 13:47:00');


-- LIKING POSTS & COMMENTS:
-- User 3 likes Post 1, 2
INSERT INTO likes (user_id, post_id) VALUES (3, 1);
-- User 2, 3 like Post 2
INSERT INTO likes (user_id, post_id) VALUES (2, 2);
INSERT INTO likes (user_id, post_id) VALUES (3, 2);

-- User 3 likes Post 3
INSERT INTO likes (user_id, post_id) VALUES (3, 3);

-- User 2 likes Comment 3
INSERT INTO likes (user_id, comment_id) VALUES (2, 3);


-- FOLLOWING:
-- User 3 follows User 1 and 2
INSERT INTO follows (follower_id, followee_id) VALUES (3, 1);
INSERT INTO follows (follower_id, followee_id) VALUES (3, 2);

-- User 2 follows User 3
INSERT INTO follows (follower_id, followee_id) VALUES (2, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

These seem to be methods well-suited for post entities because you then cache the found and reuse the likes and comments of the post.

Imagine that you have a post whose id is 123. Let's suppose further that you will need to get the comments and the likes of this post 10 times. That's 20 long, costly requests to the database if you are not careful. Instead, you can implement this pattern:

- if the comments/likes to be searched for were already computed for this post then

  - read them from cache
- else

  - read them from database
  - write them into a cache of this object

The cache for comments/likes will be a collection of comments and another for likes per post. When you read the comments of a post, your code needs to check whether they were already computed. If so, then read the results from cache rather than re-searching them in the database. For likes the same principle stands.